# Checking if an integral converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I would like to check if this define integral converges - 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x+2}{x^2-2}dx $$
Should I do it the long way?  just calculate the integral and then check ,
or is there some short way , like compare it to another function.(which I can't think about).

thanks!

Comment: The short way is to anti derive, plug in the values and see for yourself what's happening...Make a graph and establish domain.

Comment: This integral is a standard, usual Riemann integral of a continuous function in a closed interval. Of course it exists, it is not an improper one.

Comment: The intergral does funny things as x approaches $\sqrt2$ (and $-\sqrt2$)  but that isn't in your interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous in the interval $[0, 1]$, therefore it is bounded. If $|f(x)| < M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ then the absolute value of the integral is finite and smaller than $M$.

$$\left|\int_0^1f(x)\right| \leq \int_0^1\left|f(x)\right|\leq\int_0^1M=M$$

Comment: Do you have some source i can see the proof of the sentence?

Comment: Given that the length of $[0,1]$ is $1$, the bound can be chosen to be just $M$, not $2M$.

Comment: Right. WIll fix it!